# Android Development - Buttons react slowly

Tags: android, performance, button, custom-view

Question is about android development, more exactly it is about buttons and cumstom views.
I'm using four buttons in Linear Layouts and one custom view in which I draw images.
When I use method to do this (I override onDraw() ) everything works just fine, except my buttons react quite slow on pressing them. Just removing the onDraw functions leaves them working quickly.
So, my questions are:
Why do those buttons work that slow? I just cant find out why!
Do I have to use self created buttons in the custom view?

And how to solve this?

Thsi is the class I use the onDraw Method:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class test extends ImageView{  
Context mContext;
String[] medium;

final int pspawn[]={64,32};

public test(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {         
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext = context;
}

private String getMapInfo(Integer counter){
    String[] mapArray = TextUtils.split(map, " ");
    return mapArray[counter];
}
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<100; i = i+1)
    {
        String mapinfo = getMapInfo(i);
        if (mapinfo.equals("x"))
        {
            canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),R.drawable.t1), x, y, null);
        }
        x = x + 32;
        if (x == 320)
        {
            y = y + 32;
            x = 0;
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),R.drawable.t3), pspawn[0], pspawn[1],null);
        invalidate();   
    }               
}
}
```

And this is my main class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class desimain extends Activity{

private Thread worker;
private Runnable newMsg;
private OnClickListener getKeystroke;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    getKeystroke = new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch(view.getId()){   
            case R.id.Up:
                worker = new Thread(newMsg);
                worker.start();
                break;   
            case R.id.Down:   
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
                break;
            case R.id.Left:   
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
                break; 
            case R.id.Right:   
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
                break;
            }
        };
    };

    Button pressUp = (Button) findViewById (R.id.Up);
    pressUp.setOnClickListener(getKeystroke);
    Button pressDown = (Button) findViewById (R.id.Down);
    pressDown.setOnClickListener(getKeystroke);
    Button pressLeft = (Button) findViewById (R.id.Left);
    pressLeft.setOnClickListener(getKeystroke);
    Button pressRight = (Button) findViewById (R.id.Right);
    pressRight.setOnClickListener(getKeystroke);


    newMsg = new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
                    } 
                }); 
        }   
    };
}
}
```

PS: I know this code isnt very beautiful, but at the moment i just try to figure out the basics I need...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your buttons do not respond because you are taking up much too much time on the main application thread in your `onDraw()` method. Please cache your bitmaps rather than loading files from flash 200 times per draw.

Comment: Alright, i instanciated my images with `Bitmap wall =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),R.drawable.t1);` and an equivalent for the second image. Then in my loops I use `canvas.drawBitmap(wall, x, y, null);` to draw. But, anyway it doesn't help much. It goes faster, yes, but not enough. Did I get your tip wrong or is it something else? I added those changes to the onDraw Method.

Comment: @Jou: Well, that was the obvious optimization. Beyond that, use Traceview to determine where your `onDraw()` method is slow.

Comment: Thank you very much, the tip about using traceview was excellent. I found that callng the getMapInfo for the loop caused the trouble. I suppose it creates an instance of mapArray[] everytime the loop goes. Removing this by passing the whole string to the onDraw method solved the problem :))

Comment: How do I use TraceView? Thanks